# Zip operator in RxJava is not working with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to use zip operator in RxJava in android, where I am trying to execute 3 parallel API Calls to get their result together. But my zip operator is not producing result. The code for my sample problem is as follows:

Code for my gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
```

I have also included this in my gradle file

```
exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
```

Code for my Retrofit Client

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client).build();
```

Code for my API Interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/users/{UUID}/count.json")
    Observable<Count> getCountInfo(@Path("UUID") String UUID, @Query("store_id") String sort);
    @GET("v1/users/{UUID}.json")
    Observable<GetStatus> getState(@Path("UUID") String UUID);
    @GET("v1/user/{UUID}/points.json")
    Observable<Response> getResponse(@Path("UUID") String UUID);
}
```

Code for my Observables is

```
Retrofit repo = APIClient.getClient(baseUrl);
Observable<Count> userObservable = repo.create(ApiInterface.class)
    .getCount(userid,"1")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
Observable<GetStatus> eventObservable = APIClient.getClient(baseUrl)
    .create(ApiInterface.class)
    .getState(userid)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
Observable<Response> eventsObservable1 = APIClient
    .getClient(baseUrl)
    .create(ApiInterface.class)
    .getPoints(userid)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Code for my combined observable and zip operator is:

```
Observable<CommonSplashResponse> combined = Observable.zip(userObservable, eventsObservable, eventsObservable1,
new Func3<Count, GetStatus, Response, CommonResponse>() {
    @Override
    public CommonResponse call(Count count, GetStatus uStatus, 
        Response lResponse) {
        return new CommonResponse(count, uStatus, lResponse);
    }
});
combined.subscribe(new Subscriber<CommonSplashResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onNext(CommonResponse o) {
        LOG.info("Count Value is " + o.getCount());
        /**
        ***
        */
    }
});
```

The problem I am facing is that, the statements inside the onNext of the Combined Observable are not being executed.
What could be the reason for glitch in execution?
So I wanted to ask:

1. Is there any issue in my dependencies?
2. Should AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() be used instead of Schedulers.io()

Comment: it looks like one (or more) of your retrofit Observables is either emitting an error or not emitting anything at all. You might want to put some logging in your `onError` and `onCompleted`.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that, there was some issue in formation of URL, hence it was throwing 404 Exception. I debugged and caught the issue.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the .zip() operator to emit anything, all zipped observables have to emit at least once. If one of your observables emits an error, or does not emit at all, you will never receive an onNext event.

- For checking for error emissions, add logging or breakpoints into your onError within subscribe
- For checking for missing emissions, you can add doOnNext and doOnCompleted calls with logging after all your zipped Observables and see which one does not emit

Cheers!